# Spring store data in jdbcTemlate(h2 db) permanently

Tags: spring-data, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am starting to learn Spring and faced with some issues regarding spring-jdbc.
First, I tried run the example from this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/ and it worked. Then, I commented lines with droping and creating new tables(http://pastebin.com/zcJHsL1P), in order to not override data, but just get it from db and show it. However, spring showed me error:

> Table "CUSTOMERS" not found; SQL statement: ...

**So, my question is:** What should I do to store my database permanently? I don't want to recreate all time new database, I want create it once and update it.

P.S. I used H2 database. Maybe problem exists in tis db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That piece of code looks like you are "prototyping" something; so it's easier to automatically [create a new database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) (schema, tables, data) on the fly, execute and/or test whatever you want to...and finish the execution.

If you want to persist your data and only modify/update it, either use H2 with the "[file layout](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_file_layout)" or use MySQL, PostreSQL, etcetera.

By the way, the reason you are getting `Table "CUSTOMERS" not found; SQL statement: ...` is because you are using H2 as an in-memory database and every time you start your application you need to re-create the tables and populate them with data.